# I cant figure out why my prompt is not working. interface.prompt?

Tags: node.js, interface, prompt

[in this interface.prompt the word must writer don't come at Cmder ! i don't know what i'm missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV7AW.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Consider reading this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You will need to provide actual code samples (not screenshots) in order for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From Node.js docs:

> "If the readline.Interface was created with output set to null or undefined the prompt is not written."

And I see a typo in your interface configuration..look at it! 
(Hint: how do you spell output?)